# How to migrate a lot of WordPress posts to a custom post type with a custom template?

Tags: wordpress

I have a lot of posts about images. All follow the same structure - headline, description, and a download button. I would like to migrate those posts to a custom post type, so I can standardize their presentation.

I can code, but don’t know much about WP internals. My understanding is that:

1) I have to define a custom post type with the fields I need

2) Somehow to convert my old posts to the new post type

This is where I am not sure how to proceed. I understand that I will most likely need to extract the bits of data I need with regex from the content of the old posts, but where do I store the content of the new fields at the end? Should I modify the SQL tables directly or is there a WP API to do it?

If you have any useful links or instructions - please share.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a custom post type at all. Images *are* a type of post as far as WordPress is concerned: they're *attachments.* You can add an `attachment.php` template to your theme and edit it to control how it's presented. The headline (title) and description fields are already provided as post meta for images, so adding them to the template should be easy enough. Assuming that the download button is a link image URL that should also be straightforward. Check out [this link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/advanced-attachment-page/?utm_expid=3606929-91.15T0nlf8TFCqo1W_BlZjGg.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) for (exhaustive) details on adding a `attachment.php` template to your theme.

Comment: Thank you for the great idea. I will definitely explore that. However, I still would like to learn how to migrate existing posts to custom post types.